# Does numpy internally store size of an array?

Tags: python, c, numpy

From specification of a numpy array at [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject):

```
typedef struct PyArrayObject {
    PyObject_HEAD
    char *data;
    int nd;
    npy_intp *dimensions;
    npy_intp *strides;
    PyObject *base;
    PyArray_Descr *descr;
    int flags;
    PyObject *weakreflist;
} PyArrayObject;
```

When I look at the specification of a numpy array, I don't see that it stores number of elements of the array. Is that really the case?

What is the advantage of not storing that?

Thank you.

Comment: It appears as if it stores arrays of both dimensions and strides, however. In most implementations involving array operations, this is the information actually required rather than total number of items which does nothing to help you access them systematically.

Comment: I guess I get this now. When the size of array is large, multiplying the dimensions to get the size would only take a tiny fraction of time for the whole calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size (that is, the total number of elements in the array) is computed as the product of the values in the array `dimensions`.  The length of that array is `nd`.

In the C code that implements the core of numpy, you'll find many uses of the macro `PyArray_SIZE(obj)`.  Here's the definition of that macro:

```
#define PyArray_SIZE(m) PyArray_MultiplyList(PyArray_DIMS(m), PyArray_NDIM(m))
```

The advantage of not storing it is, well, not storing redundant data.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `PyArray_ArrayDescr *PyArray_Descr.subarray`:

> If this is non- NULL, then this data-type descriptor is a C-style
>   contiguous array of another data-type descriptor. In other-words, each
>   element that this descriptor describes is actually an array of some
>   other base descriptor. This is most useful as the data-type descriptor
>   for a field in another data-type descriptor. The fields member should
>   be NULL if this is non- NULL (the fields member of the base descriptor
>   can be non- NULL however). The PyArray_ArrayDescr structure is defined
>   using

```
typedef struct {
    PyArray_Descr *base;
    PyObject *shape;      /* <-------- */
} PyArray_ArrayDescr;
```

and:

```
PyObject *PyArray_ArrayDescr.shape
```

> The shape (always C-style contiguous) of the sub-array as a Python tuple.